# @ character before a function call

Tags: php

What is the difference between these two function calls in PHP?

```
init_get($somevariable);

@init_get($somevariable);
```

Comment: the "@" will close any php errors and notices

Answer (score 249, accepted):

the "@" will silence any php errors your function could raise.

Comment: But what if you put `@` in front of PHP's `trigger_error` function? I have seen that in some code, but its behavior is inconsistent for me so far. In some cases, I do see the error being reported by the configured error handler and in other cases it does seem to get reported.

Comment: The `@` will temporarily set `error_reporting` to 0 but will not "suppress" the error.

Answer (score 50):

It silences errors and warnings. See [Error Control Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).

Answer (score 41):

As already answered the `@` will stop the error (if any) from showing up.
In terms of performance this is not recommended.

What php is doing is:

- reading the error display state
- setting the error display to show no errors
- running your function
- setting the error display to it's previous state

If you don't want any errors showing up use `error_reporting(0);`.

Or just write bug free code :P

Comment: Prefer to put zero, but if that works, great didn't know about it :)

Comment: What about functions that you do not control, like mail for example? Which other options exist? I am using @ right now, but would be great to be able to do in different way

Answer (score 8):

http://www.faqts.com/knowledge_base/view.phtml/aid/18068/fid/38

All PHP expressions can be called with the "@" prefix, which turns off 
error reporting for that particular expression.

Answer (score 6):

As everyone said, it stops the output of errors for that particular function. However, this decreases performance greatly since it has to change the error display setting twice. I would recommend NOT ignoring warnings or errors and fixing the code instead.

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers. That code is not mine, I was only looking at the phpBB code for curiosity, so I have no problems of performance. :) Thanks again.