# How to image resize

Tags: php

Can you help me in this regard. I am loading the image form, but I do not know how to resize it. The codes are as followings.

```
$gelenisimadi    = $_FILES["resim"]["name"];
$gelenisimturu   = $_FILES["resim"]["type"];
$gelenisimdizini = $_FILES["resim"]["tmp_name"];

$resimuzantisinibul = @substr($gelenisimadi,-4);
$resmiisimlendir    = @substr(md5(@uniqid(rand())),0,20);
$yeniresimadi       = $resmiisimlendir.$resimuzantisinibul;
$resimyukle         = @move_uploaded_file($gelenisimdizini,$dosyayolu.$yeniresimadi);

if($resimyukle){
  $sitekle = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO site (foto) VALUES ('$yeniresimadi')");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize image PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650572/resize-image-php)

Comment: ...and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649645/resize-image-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP GD library which has image function and You can easily resize the image.

Click [here](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php)! To read in detail

Answer (score 0):

1. please use the search function! [resize image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649645/resize-image-in-php)
2. found in php manual:  http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagecopyresampled.php
3. further i allow my self a comment: the @-character before a function blocks all warning/error output. to end up with proper code, you should do a proper errorhandling instead of this. I don't see the reason for @substr(....
   [PHP: @ character before a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002610/php-character-before-a-function-call)