# Download the contents of a URL in PHP even if it returns a 404

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

I want to download the contents of a URL using PHP, even if the HTTP response code is 404. `file_get_contents` will error out, and I wasn't able to find an answer using Google. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) only returns the content of HTTP 200 responses.

[With curl you get the headers and the content separately.](http://devzone.zend.com/160/using-curl-and-libcurl-with-php/)

As of PHP 5.0, you can also specify a context for `file_get_contents`, allowing you to do it without relying on url (See Gordon's answer).

Answer (score 71):

You have to [configure the stream wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) to ignore errors:

> **ignore_errors** `boolean` Fetch the content even on failure status codes. Defaults to `FALSE`

In other words, do

```
echo file_get_contents(
    'http://stackoverflow.com/foo/bar',
    false,
    stream_context_create([
        'http' => [
            'ignore_errors' => true,
        ],
    ])
);
```

and you will get the 404 page.

If you want this to be the default behavior for HTTP streams, use

```
stream_context_set_default(
    array('http' => array(
        'ignore_errors' => true)
    )
);
```

Any calls using the HTTP stream wrapper will use these settings then, e.g. you can simply do

```
echo file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/foo/bar');
```

If you also want to get the [response header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php), just do

```
print_r($http_response_header);
```

after the call. The variable is (re-)populated after each call with a http stream wrapper.

Comment: Interesting approach - but can you tell if you got an error or a successful response?

Comment: +1 Gordon is right, the variable $http_response_header contains exactly what it says on the tin, which obviously includes the status code.

Answer (score 3):

Use [cURL](http://www.php.net/curl) instead. It allows much greater control, and will let you read any content retrieved and the status code.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: check the return code:
 `$content = file_get_contents("websitelink");
 if($content === FALSE) { // handle error here... }`

Step 2: suppress the warning by putting an error control operator (i.e. `@`) in front of the call to file_get_contents(): `$content = @file_get_contents($site);`