# Codeigniter API error returning

Tags: api, codeigniter, rest, php

Hi has anyone any experience using Phil Sturgeons RESTFUL libraries for codeigniter. I've decided to create a web service for our database in order to supply access to the database from multiple applications. The website is currently developed in Codeigniter therefore it was a simple solution to use the rest API libraries.

The problem I have is that I am trying to return specific errors in the event of a problem.

At the moment I am purposely returning an error like so:

```
require(APPPATH . 'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class Settings_api extends REST_Controller {

    function settings_get()
    {
        $this->response(NULL, 404);
    }
}
```

If I access the url directly then I am just receiving a blank page, I can return a message if I replace the 'NULL' with a message but there is nothing to say its a 404 error whereas If I call the page via php using the following

```
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.example.co.uk/api/settings_api/settings/'));

echo $user;
```

then it shows the following line

```
Message: file_get_contents(http://www.example.co.uk/api/settings_api/settings/) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404
```

In both instances I would like to return a 404 error along with a message I provide. Is this possible and if so could you point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: A 404 is a 404, it means what you requested doesn't exist, at all. You shouldn't call a 404 purposely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message being generated by PHP, as far as I know, there's nothing you can do about this (other than using the `@` operator, which I do NOT recommend). So, your only option is to manually check `file_get_content()`'s return value:

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://...');

if ($response === false) {
    // return whatever you feel is appropriate
} else {
    $user = json_decode($response);
    echo $user;
}
```

**EDIT**
Found this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6718657/264395) on Stackoverflow which is what you are looking for.

Comment: I see, this would be fine if I were only using the api myself but the chances are it will be passed on to other developers to integrate with their own applications therefore I would prefer to return something more specific to the problem. I am able to return a message providing I do not return the http response code along with it, would you think it more suitable to do it this way or is an http response code necessary

Comment: thanks for the update. That makes more sense now, suppose I'll just have to include something like that in any documentation I provide to other users of the api. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should always check if `response !== false`, think about network errors.