# Having some issue with ajax and PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to get the ajax data in `PHP` variable. The code is working fine and I am able to get the ajax data in `PHP` variable.

My question is : Can I use the `PHP` variable for `file_get_contents` function again ?

My PHP code is like this

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('https://someurl.com');
if (isset($_POST['job']))
{
$job = $_POST['job'];
$attrb = $_POST['attrb'];
echo $job;
echo $attrb;
$htmlcontents = file_get_contents($attrb);
}
?>
```

And the Ajax code is as below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.post("test.php",
    {
      job: exactdatainner,
      attrb: getattr
    },
    function(data,status){

      var obj = data.split('http');
        var title = obj[0];
        var link = 'http' + obj[1];
        $(".job").html(title);
        $(".attribute").html(link);
    });
});
```

This code works fine for the first step, sending data from `ajax` and receiving response and print the result in a `Div`.

Now I am trying to fetch the URL (this URL was created in first step and stored in a `PHP` variable. Code is : `$attrb = $_POST['attrb'];`)

[image]

As you can see that I am able to print the value in first step, but when I am trying to get the contents of URL again, it gives me the error.

Comment: Yes you can , but Whether it will be success or not deepens on the value of (`$htmlcontents = file_get_contents($attrb);`) `$attrb`

Comment: I am getting error `( ! ) Warning: file_get_contents(`

Comment: Mention the Error in your question, also give more detail of the error

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari I have edited the question with error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code, I tested and it's working. Returning a `404 response <h1>Sorry This Page is Not Available Now</h1>` and I also verified the response by hitting the same url in the browser, so it's working.

> `file_get_contents()` stops with a warning  errors for non-2xx status codes.
>   You just need to fetch the contents even on failure status code maybe `404` or `500`, for that you need to set `ignore_errors => true`,default is false.

```
 echo file_get_contents(
'https://www.sarkariresult.com/force/navy-sst',
false,
stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'ignore_errors' => true
    ],
]) );
```

More information have a look on this question, second answer. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718598/download-the-contents-of-a-url-in-php-even-if-it-returns-a-404)

**Update**

```
$url = 'https://html5andcss3.org/';
$opts = array(
           'http'=>array(
           'method'=>"GET",
           'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n",
           'ignore_errors' => true, //set to true for non 2XXX reponse codes

               )
           );

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents($a, false, $context);//pass the variable $url
echo $file;
```

Comment: If I put the right ULR like https://html5andcss3.org. It's printing blank page. And second thing, If I have the URL stored in variable, it again saying error message, sorry This page is not available right now.

Comment: @SwapnilRajja make sure you prefix the url with `http://` or `https://`

Comment: I'm calling the URL inside `If` condition and it's not working. But If I call it outside the `If` condition, it's working fine.

But this doesn't work with variable. I have to put the URL address manually.

Comment: Same Error of 404 response

I think the issue is on the above code where I am getting the data from ajax. The variable `$attrb` is returning with null value (my thought).

Comment: When I check your code on another page, it's working fine. I need to fetch the URL, which was sent from ajax and received in PHP variable `$attrb`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195727/discussion-between-swapnil-rajja-and-sujeet-agrahari).