# How to skip code when file_get_contents fails?

Tags: php

When I use a valid URL like the following, `file_get_contents` will return html code

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/");
```

but if the URL was invalid:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.go1235ogle.com/"); //Invalid URL. This line give Error Message
```

my code will output an error message `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

if `file_get_contents` can't open a given URL, I want to hide the error message it's outputting and skip the code bellow it with an `if else` statement.

```
if (FALSE === $html) 
{
  //skip the code in here ?
}
```

but the code above doesn't help. Can you please tell me how can I correct this problem?

Comment: Which line gives you the error message?

Comment: That error is *not* triggered by that line. Please check the exact line reported in the notice. Most likely, you go ahead and use `$html` normally even when it's empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (FALSE === $html) 
{
  // TODO: handle the case when file_get_contents fails
} else {
  // TODO: handle the case when file_get_contents succeeds
}
```

To get rid of the `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`, either turn off outputting error messages completely by turning [`display_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) off (recommended in a production environment), or set [`error_reporting`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) to a lower level.

However, the code you posted should not produce a `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. It helped a lot.

Comment: Yeah, hiding those annoying error messages is always better than fixing the code ;-P

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Exactly my point. However, if you intend to fix the code instead, that's what the code fragment at the top of my answer is intended for.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Some PHP functions print warnings even if it is unapropriate. In my opinion, a warning is unapropriate if the programmer can do nothing to prevent the warning. Take fopen for example. It emits a warning if you try to open a HTTP stream of a host that is currently down. This makes it necessary for PHP programmers, to know how to supress notices, warnings and error messages.

Answer (score 7):

You can hide the error by adding a @

```
$html = @file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/");
if ($html === FALSE){
  // Error
}
else {
  // No errors
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/272377/1907875

Answer (score 0):

You want to execute the code, unless the value is false, so put the code in a `if (false !== $html)` block

Answer (score 0):

That line doesn't produce an error, you need to check the rest of your code as you've probably used `$html` later on.