# PHP file_get_contents by an 404

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm getting JSON arrays with `file_get_contents`, but if the page doesn't exist I want to give an message: Player not found. But now I get this error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(urlwithan404errorhere)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in -------

I don't get this error when the api gives me an correct JSON array.

This is the code is use:

```
$gegevens = file_get_contents('');      
$array_2 = json_decode($gegevens, TRUE);
$summonerid = $array_2[$naam]["id"];
```

Comment: If you are planning on working a lot with services, i suggest you take a look at guzzle, https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle, instead of doing this kind of stuf with file_get_contents. You will get cleaner and better code.

Comment: I just use it once, so no thanks :D

Comment: This topic is already awnsered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272361/how-can-i-handle-the-warning-of-file-get-contents-function-in-php:

Answer (score 1):

Your code could become like this:

```
$gegevens = @file_get_contents('');      

if ($gegevens !== FALSE) {
    $array_2 = json_decode($gegevens, TRUE);
    $summonerid = $array_2[$naam]["id"];
} else {
    $summonerid = 0;
}
```

**Explanations:**
* the `@` in front of `file_get_contents` is to stop showing php error in case the request failed.
* if the `$summonerid` equals to `0`, then you have no player found

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
if (($gegevens = @file_get_contents('')) === false) {
    printf("<h1>Player not found!</h1>\n");
    return;
}

// ... continue here ...
```

The `@` will suppress any error message if `file_get_contents()`fails. It will return `false`in this case (use `===` for comparison to avoid confusion with empty files), which you can use for failure detection.