# file_get_contents() returns literal 'Not Found' instead of boolean

Tags: php, php-5.4

This is the code I am using:

```
<?php 
$changelog="https://raw.github.com/neurobin/oraji/release/ChangeLog";
$filec1=@file_get_contents($changelog);

if($filec1===false) {$filec1="something";}

echo $filec1
?>
```

It prints *Not Found* instead of *something*. But when I add another condition to the if statement like this:

```
if($filec1===false||$filec1=="Not Found") {$filec1="something";}
```

Then it works as expected.

What's going wrong here?

PHP version is 5.4. `php -v` output:

```
PHP 5.4.45 (cli) (built: Oct 29 2015 09:16:10) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.7.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2013, by Zend Technologies
    with Suhosin v0.9.36, Copyright (c) 2007-2014, by SektionEins GmbH
```

N.B: I am doing this on a remote server.

---

**EDIT:**

Anyway, I noticed (going to that URL in browser) that Github is sending literal 'Not Found' as a content for that non-existing URL (I don't know why). But how can I workaround it (without using a literal string as conditional)?

This is what I ended up doing:

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/617721/3744681), I am checking for the HTTP header response and targeting `200` as a success code and failure otherwise (along with a true/false check).

```
<?php 
function fileGetContents($file){
    $filec1=@file_get_contents($file);
    if($filec1===false || !strpos($http_response_header[0], "200")) 
        {$filec1="something";}
    return $filec1;
}

$changelog="https://raw.github.com/neurobin/oraji/release/ChangeLog";
$filec1=fileGetContents($changelog);

echo $filec1;
?>
```

**Note:**

If a 301/302 redirect is used then this won't work. For example, if the above link did even exist, it wouldn't work i.e it would return 'something' instead of the actual content in the redirected page. Because `raw.github.com` is redirected to `raw.githubusercontent.com`

**This solution only works if I use the actual URL with no redirection.
So this is still not a good solution to go for.**

Comment: the url given itself returning the string `not found`, that's why it's working.

Comment: The string "Not Found" seems like the body of the page. Are you sure that $changelog is the correct URL and is reachable from remote?

Comment: Both of above commentators are telling the right thing.

Comment: If github doesn't return a "200 OK" status, you could use that. In order to do that, use an HTTP client library like CURL or Guzzle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as expected:

The logic is simple:

> Redirect or not, there will be a `200 OK` somewhere in `$http_response_header` array if the URL is valid.

So, I just check over all elements of the array for a `200 OK` message.

```
<?php 
function is200OK($arr){
    foreach($arr as $str){
        if(strpos($str, " 200 OK")) {return true;}
    }
    return false;
}

function fileGetContents($file){
    $filec1=@file_get_contents($file);
    if($filec1===false || !is200OK($http_response_header)) {$filec1="something";}
    //print_r($http_response_header);
    return $filec1;
}

$changelog="https://raw.github.com/neurobin/oraji/release/ChangeLog";
$filec1=fileGetContents($changelog);

echo $filec1;
?>
```

Comment: That's kinda hardore :) Anyway, I still can't see a better way to do it with `file_get_contents`...

Answer (score 1):

Use [$http_response_header](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php):

```
$changelog="https://raw.github.com/neurobin/oraji/release/ChangeLog";
$filec1=@file_get_contents($changelog);

if($filec1===false || $http_response_header[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {$filec1="something";}
```

Comment: I figured, looking to header response is the way to go. but somehow your method didn't get me the result. Just looking at `200` seems the way to go. copied from http://stackoverflow.com/a/617721/3744681

Comment: I've uploaded the script to my remote host and github gives me 301 code. So, yes, with such behavior of github it's more likely to just search for 200 in response code.

Comment: Please look at my edit. My solution has a major flaw.

Comment: Seems like it's better to use `CURL` in this situation. Get with it the requested URL and parse curl's result.

Comment: I have edited and undeleted my answer. It seems to work. Let me know if you find any flaws in it.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `file_get_contents` in a conditional.

```
$changelog="https://raw.github.com/neurobin/oraji/release/ChangeLog";
if($filec1 = @file_get_contents($changelog)) {
    echo 'Got it';
} else {
    echo 'NOOOOOoooo!';
}
```

Also note if you take off the `@` you are given an error.

Comment: It doesn't work how, you don't get `Noooo!` or you want some other behavior?

Comment: It gets me Not Found.

Comment: I've tested on PHP 5.2 locally and it works as expected. Tested 4.3-7 here, and works as expected, https://3v4l.org/bZkHB. Is that the actual URL?

Comment: On local host my original code works too. But not in remote... I don't know what is Github doing internally to produce this kind of behavior.

Comment: @Switcher You get the `NOOOOOoooo!` which is the intended result/behavior.. Seems OPs remote server is configured strangely.

Comment: Yep, that's pretty weird. Github's code logic and the difference in file_get_contents result....

Comment: @chris85, I think I've got it. Github gives redirect(301) to Not Found page(404). My remote doesn't follow the redirect.

Comment: @Switcher take off the `@` and I think you will get varying `404` warning; https://3v4l.org/Pft2G all still result in the `Noooo!` though. Can't see an instance where it would result in true..

Answer (score 0):

Well,if you access the link you will see you get that error. Links which returns json , look like an array even if they are in web.