# Test if PHP `copy` can download file from internet

Tags: php, laravel, bitbucket-pipelines

I have written a function, with an unit test, to download an image using PHP

```
// ...
if (!copy($url, $imagePath)) {
    return null;
}
// ...
```

It works locally but in [Bitbucket Pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines) the unit test fails. The file couldn't be downloaded (file not found in storage).

It might has been disabled on purpose. So I would like to run this unit test only if `copy()` can download external files.

I tried this but didn't work:

```
public function test_downloadImage()
{
    if (!ini_get('allow_url_fopen') || in_array('copy', explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions')))) {
        return;
    }
    // download the image...
    // assert file exists...
}
```

How can I test if `copy()` can download external files?

Thank you.

## Problem solved

Sorry for this but the problem didn't came from PHP `copy()`.

It was trying to download an image to a non-existing directory. In fact, I forgot to setup the [Laravel Public directory  symbolic link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk). It was already setup on my computer.

Comment: You might use curl instead? It is a much more full-featured client for remote file fetching. It has timeout settings, it returns HTTP response codes, etc. You can easily check if it's installed with extension_loaded("curl")

Comment: Just use **file_get_contents** with the URL.  Remember, you're not building for the client side, and unless you are working on an open source project that is likely to be distributed all over the place, once it works on your server - you're all set.

Answer (score 1):

Use `curl` to initiate a HEAD request:

```
function url_is_readable($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'HEAD');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    return false !== $res;
}
```

Then test away:

```
var_dump(url_is_readable('https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/im_so_random.png'));
var_dump(url_is_readable('http://whyohwhy.example.co/monkey.png'));
```

You can then use `curl` to perform a copy. This has a few benefits. First, it works independent of whether `allow_url_fopen` has been turned off. Second, `curl` gives you much more control, diagnostics, and error information. Third, it's cooler. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem actually came from somewhere else. Please see my edits.

Answer (score 0):

Consider switching to curl as `allow_url_fopen` is often disabled for security reasons.

---

However to answer your question, you can use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272361/how-can-i-handle-the-warning-of-file-get-contents-function-in-php) for file_get_contents() to check if you can get content from the web.

1. Suppress the warning with an @ in front of the `file_get_contents` (as suggested by the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#refsect1-function.fopen-errors), but do NOT use this if you can avoid it)
2. Check return value for `null`
3. Throw Exception

Example:

```
public function test_downloadImage($path)
{
    $contents = @file_get_contents($path);
    if($contents === null) {
        $error = error_get_last();
        throw new Exception($error['message']);
    }
    return $contents;
}
```

Call this function with try/catch:

```
try {
    $fileContent = test_downloadImage('http://stackoverflow.com')
    // Success, do something with your file
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Download failed, log error from $e->getMessage(), show message to user
}
```

Comment: Please don't recommend `@`-suppression.

Comment: True, but there seems to be no other solution for this question except for `set_error_handler`, which is probably also disabled when `ini_get` is. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: PHP 7 allows you to catch those exceptions in a `try`-`catch` block.

Comment: Then you'll have to check first if you're running PHP7... In fact the PHP manual suggests using @ in this specific case: http://www.php.net/function.fopen