# SSRS SDK For PHP : Not working from PHP 5.5

Tags: php, reporting-services, sdk, ssrs-2014

I'm using the [SSRS SDK For PHP](https://ssrsphp.codeplex.com/) which has not been updated since years surprisingly (08.04.2010) . 
It works fine under PHP 5.4 (5.4.44) but not under 5.5+ (5.5.37, 5.6.28, 7.x)

The error is :

> array ( )Failed to connect to Reporting Service Make sure that the url
>   (https://myHost:60004/ReportServer/) and credentials are
>   correct!

The exception is thrown in line 207 because the var $content is equals to FALSE (so can't load the content).

It's perfectly fine with PHP 5.4.44.

I can't find the "SSRS SDK For PHP" documentation regarding the PHP version supported...

I'm not using any framework such as Symfony2, CakePHP, Zend Framework,... except Bootstrap.

Does anyone know or have figured out this issue?

**EDIT**

As asked in a comment, here is my code :

```
function buildSSRSReport($companyId)
    {
        require_once '../tools/SSRSReport/SSRSReport.php';

        try {
            // Create a connection to the SSRS Server
            $rs = new SSRSReport(new Credentials(SSRS_USER_ID, SSRS_PASSWORD), SSRS_REPORT_SERVER_URL);
            $sqlConnection = self::getSqlConnection();

            // Load the report and specify the params required for its execution
            $executionInfo = $rs->LoadReport2(self::getSSRSEnvironment(), NULL);
            $parameters = array();
            $parameters[0] = new ParameterValue();
            $parameters[0]->Name = "CompanyId";
            $parameters[0]->Value = $companyId;
            $rs->SetExecutionParameters2($parameters);

            // Require the Report to be rendered in HTML format
            $renderAsHTML = new RenderAsPDF();

            // Set the links in the reports to point to the php app
            //$renderAsHTML->ReplacementRoot = getPageURL();

            // Set the root path on the server for any image included in the report
            //$renderAsHTML->StreamRoot = './images/';

            // Execute the Report
            $result_html = $rs->Render2($renderAsHTML,
                PageCountModeEnum::$Actual,
                $Extension,
                $MimeType,
                $Encoding,
                $Warnings,
                $StreamIds);

            $pdfFileName = self::getCompanyAlias($sqlConnection, $companyId) . ".pdf";

            header('Content-Type: application/x-download');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $pdfFileName . '"');
            header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');

            return $result_html;
        } catch (SSRSReportException $serviceException) {
            echo $serviceException->GetErrorMessage();
        }

    }

    function getSSRSEnvironment()
    {
        return "/DEV/CompanyESGReportingServices-DEV/Main";
    }

    private function getSqlConnection()
    {
        require_once("../inc/eth_connexion.php");
        /* These 4 variables are contained within the eth_connexion.php file */
        $serverName = SQL_SERVERNAME;
        $userName = SQL_USERNAME;
        $dbName = SQL_DATABASENAME;
        $password = SQL_PASSWORD;

        // SQLSRV : Connection array used when calling SQL via sqlsrv_query
        $connectionInfo = array("Database"=> SQL_DATABASENAME,
            "UID"=> SQL_USERNAME,
            "PWD"=> SQL_PASSWORD,
            "ReturnDatesAsStrings" => true);

        $sqlConnection = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
        if (!$sqlConnection) {
            die('Can't log to the database');
        }

        return $sqlConnection;
    }
```

And here is the source code of the SSRSReport constructor (original from the SSRS SDK For PHP) :

```
public function SSRSReport($credentials, $url, $proxy = null)
{        
    $this->_BaseUrl = ($url[strlen($url) - 1] == '/')? $url : $url . '/';
    $executionServiceUrl = $this->_BaseUrl . self::ExecutionService;
    $managementServiceUrl = $this->_BaseUrl . self::ManagementService;

    $options = $credentials->getCredentails();
    $stream_conext_params = array( 'http' =>
                                     array('header' =>
                                      array($credentials->getBase64Auth())));
    if(isset($proxy))
    {
        $options = array_merge($options, $proxy->getProxy());
        $stream_conext_params['http']['proxy'] = 'tcp://' .
                                                    $proxy->getHost() .
                                                    ':' .
                                                    $proxy->getPort();
        if($proxy->getLogin() != null)
        {               
            $stream_conext_params['http']['header'][1] = $proxy->getBase64Auth();
        }            
    }

    /**
     * If the SoapClient call fails, we cannot catch exception or supress warning
     * since it throws php fatal exception.
     * http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34657
     * So try to load the wsdl by
     * calling file_get_contents (with warning supressed i.e. using @ symbol
     * infront of the function call)
     * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272361/how-can-i-handle-the-warning-of-filegetcontents-function-in-php
     */
    $context = stream_context_create($stream_conext_params);
    $content = @file_get_contents($executionServiceUrl, false, $context);
    if ($content === FALSE) // I'M GOING HERE WITH PHP 5.5+ 
    {
        throw new SSRSReportException("",
                    "Failed to connect to Reporting Service  <br/> Make sure " .
                    "that the url ($this->_BaseUrl) and credentials are correct!");
    }

    $this->_soapHandle_Exe =  new SoapClient ($executionServiceUrl, $options);
    $this->_soapHandle_Mgt =  new SoapClient ($managementServiceUrl, $options);
    $this->ClearRequest();
}
```

The exact error message is :

> https://myPublicHostProvider:60004/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx?wsdl
>   Authorization: Basic = array(1) {
>   ["http"]=> array(1) { ["header"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(57)
>   "Authorization: Basic =" } } }
>   Failed to connect to Reporting Service
>   Make sure that the url (https://myPublicHostProvider:60004/ReportServer/) and credentials are correct!

Comment: Does anyone use this SDK and encounter the same problem when using with a newer PHP version (5.5+) ?

Comment: Yes, I am using this SDK on PHP 7.1. Could you clarify the exact error message you were presented and if possible, the source code related to the SSRS Connection.

Comment: Thanks for your message and telling me that this SDK work on your side with PHP 7.1. It's my goal to migrate to latest PHP version. I've edited my post above to add the source code of my function calling the SDK. I've also added the exact error message I'm getting

Comment: Have you enabled the Basic Authentication on your Report Server? As far as I can tell, there's not much difference with the code you are using compared to mine. I'll be posting an answer with the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help MiSAKACHi. It pointed me on the right direction. Actually, I'm using a remote dedicated server on a hosting provider on which I don't have access. But the `<RSWindowsBasic/>` is there as it can load the report with PHP 5.4. Everything is fine under this version.

Thanks to you, I found the issue : I'm using HTTPS and with HTTPS it doesn't work whereas it works when I'm using HTTP !
I'm check with my hosting provider if they can do something.

**EDIT - Solution**

My hosting provider fixed the issue last year (forgot to post it here). During the time it wasn't fixed, I was still under PHP 5.4. 
I paste their original message :

> These issues that you describe is because the installed Certificate is a self signed Certificate. New Web Browsers and PHP Version don't accept these Certificates because of Security Risks.
>
> We have changed the Certificate with a official issued Certificate

Answer (score 1):

> SSRS SDK for PHP Configuration Pointers

- Make sure your Report Server instance is accessible. Test it by going to the Web Portal or the Service URL.
- Provide your credentials. If you are authenticated, then the credentials that you used are valid.
- After that, go to the directory `\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<INSTANCE_NAME>\Reporting Services\ReportServer` and look for the file named `rsreportserver.config`
- Find this snippet

  ```
  <Authentication>
  <AuthenticationTypes>
      <RSWindowsNTLM/>
  </AuthenticationTypes>
  <Authentication>
  ```
- Add `<RSWindowsBasic/>` below the `<RSWindowsNTLM/>` entry.

> For your reference, this was the snippet I used to test my instance during configuration.

```
require_once( 'SSRSReport\bin\SSRSReport.php' );

define( 'UID', 'DOMAIN\Username' );
define( 'PASWD', 'Password' );
define( 'SERVICE_URL', 'http://127.0.0.1/SERVICE_URL/' );

try {
    $ssrs_report = new SSRSReport( new Credentials( UID, PASWD ), SERVICE_URL );
    $ssrs_report->LoadReport2( '/test', NULL );
    $renderAsHTML = new RenderAsHTML();
    $result_html = $ssrs_report->Render2(
        $renderAsHTML,
        PageCountModeEnum::$Estimate,
        $Extension,
        $MimeType,
        $Encoding,
        $Warnings,
        $StreamIds
    );
    echo $result_html;  
} catch ( SSRSReportException $serviceException ) {
    echo $serviceException->GetErrorMessage();
}
```

It can successfully load the RDL that is located on the load path.

Comment: Thanks for you code. It's basically the same as mine except you're rendering in HTML (PDF for me) and with PageCountModeEnum::$Estimate ($Actual for me). I see that you're using HTTP, does it works with HTTPS under PHP 5.5+ (7.1 in your case) ?

Comment: I was able to setup an HTTPS instance but I have not tested it. Given that, I think it should also work on HTTPS.

Comment: ok I also think it should work but here is the fact for me :). Please let me know if one day you test it under HTTPS and you can make it working. Thanks. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that I was facing issue using the [codeplex ssrsphp](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=ssrsphp), therefore I googled and found another SDK, which works perfectly. I'm using PHP 7+. [ChartBlocks/php-ssrs](https://github.com/ChartBlocks/php-ssrs) is the SDK, and I'm available if there're any questions related to this.

Comment: There are two good SDKs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52820347/2415524