# Is there any update of SSRS PHP SDK for SQL Server 2016?

Tags: php, reporting-services

I would like to connect my PHP application with SSRS.
I followed the steps found from Microsoft here 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2010/05/04/getting-started-with-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-and-php/ .

I downloaded the SDK from this page https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=ssrsphp
but the file does not have any instructions how to install it. It seems like this SDK as as open project is not supported any more (first released on 2010).

Could anyone demonstrate a basic example code connecting php application with SSRS 2016 calling a sample report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two 'updated' versions available on GitHub that are based on the original 2010 SDK. I've been playing with both with some success.

[ChartBlocks/php-ssrs](https://github.com/ChartBlocks/php-ssrs)

[EmergencyReporting/ssrsreport](https://github.com/EmergencyReporting/ssrsreport)

I don't use composer, so I had difficulty to get the 'EmergencyReporting' solution to link/autoload correctly.

I did get Chartblocks working, but only for rendering the report in HTML, no controls like a C# .NET Report Viewer Control.

If anyone out there knows of a true PHP Report Viewer Control, please let me know.  I'm going to go play with iframes now =(

Comment: I haven't had time to work on this since last year.  Has anyone else out there made any progress?

Comment: I got the EmergencyReporting solution to work on a Drupal site. It's a library so all I had to do was put it in the libraries folder. I did however have to install the xautoload module and update the code that was making use of the library to use namespaces. I even got a PR merged last year, so bug fixes can still be made if needed.

Comment: These libraries are not maintained anymore, and I really hope to find an alternative.