# Unable to catch PHP file_get_contents error using try catch block

Tags: php, error-handling

I am trying to fetch an image using `file_get_contents` function but it gives an error. To handle the error I am using try catch block but it does not catch the error and fails.

My code:

```
try {
     $url = 'http://wxdex.ocm/pdd.jpg'; //dummy url
     $file_content = file_get_contents($url);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
     echo 'Error Caught';           
}
```

Error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known
Warning: file_get_contents(http://wxdex.ocm/pdd.jpg): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

**NOTE:: I am able to fetch any other valid image url on remote.**

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272361/how-can-i-handle-the-warning-of-file-get-contents-function-in-php

Comment: Main thing is that it's a warning and not an error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`try/catch` doesn't work because a `warning` is not an `exception`.

You can try this code so you can catch warnings as well.

```
//set your own error handler before the call
set_error_handler(function ($err_severity, $err_msg, $err_file, $err_line, array $err_context)
{
    throw new ErrorException( $err_msg, 0, $err_severity, $err_file, $err_line );
}, E_WARNING);

try {
    $url = 'http://wxdex.ocm/pdd.jpg';
    $file_content = file_get_contents($url);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error Caught'; 
}

//restore the previous error handler
restore_error_handler();
```

Comment: Be cautious when automagically converting warnings to exceptions: any minor issue will abort the whole program if you don't explicitly catch it at the right point. Also, `set_error_handler()` overrides any previous handler you might have defined.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález that's why i have used restore_error_handler() after that

Comment: super fix.. It helped me lot

Answer (score 1):

Following is the altenative way , just need to check for the data , if not we can throw the exception to handle it. it will be safer compared with setting the new error handler

```
try {
    $url = 'http://wxdex.ocm/pdd.jpg';
    $file_content = file_get_contents($url);
    if(empty($file_content)){
       throw new Exception("failed to open stream ", 1);
    }else{
       echo "File is loaded and content is there";
     }

} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo 'Error Caught'; 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. It throws a warning, so I had to use @ to suppress the warning. Thanks though.

Comment: it returns the same error originally displayed in the browser ... at least it helps the application not to stop due to the error ...

Answer (score 0):

check URL exist before that using get header function

```
$url = 'http://wxdex.ocm/pdd.jpg';
$file_headers = @get_headers($url);

if(!$file_headers || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found' ||trim($file_headers[0]) == 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden') {
    $exists = false;
}else{
    $exists = true;
}
if($exists===true){

    $file_content = file_get_contents($url);
}
```

Comment: this is not good solution as `@get_headers()` just silencing errors or warning. we can straight away use `@file_get_contents()` to see if that returns any value.