# How do I ignore PHP notice in the result of file_get_content?

Tags: json, file-get-contents

I am using `file_get_content` to get some JSON string from an API. However sometimes the API returns a PHP notice along with the JSON string, which makes my `JSON_decode" broken. Is there anyway to ignore the notice and get the JSON string only?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272361/how-can-i-handle-the-warning-of-file-get-contents-function-in-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I handle the warning of file\_get\_contents() function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272361/how-can-i-handle-the-warning-of-file-get-contents-function-in-php)