# PHP - file_get_contents() works perfectly on localhost but on live server

Tags: php

I have been trying to get the html content from a webpage using file_get_contents(). It works perfectly on localhost but not on live server.

Some more information is as follows:

- PHP version is 7+
- http, https are included in Registered PHP Streams
- allow_url_fopen is On
- used cURL, but it redirects to some other page and uses my domain as the referrer.
- executing this in the browser by putting the code in a php file
- output of the below code on live server is `false`

```
$url = 'https://trafficsecrets.com/ts-free-book';

$context = stream_context_create(
    array (
        'http' => array (
            'method' => 'GET',
            'follow_location' => true,
            'max_redirects' => 5,
            'header' => array('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.2) Gecko/20110201', ),
        ),
        "ssl"=>array(
            "verify_peer"=>false,
            "verify_peer_name"=>false,
        ),
    )
);
echo var_dump(file_get_contents($url, false, $context));
```

Why this code gives the html on localhost and not on the server?

Comment: Which exactly output do you get after running `var_dump(file_get_contents($url, false, $context));`? The `file_get_contents` function might return `false` on failure.

Comment: Yes, it returns `false` when executed on the live server.

Comment: _"allow_url_fopen is On"_ How do you know this for certain?

Comment: @kmoser checked it using `phpinfo()` and `ini_get('allow_url_fopen')`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this to catch the error:

```php
set_error_handler(
    function ($severity, $message, $file, $line) {
        throw new ErrorException($message, $severity, $severity, $file, $line);
    }
);

try {
    file_get_contents($url, false, $context));
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

restore_error_handler();
```

Source: [How can I handle the warning of file_get_contents() function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272361/how-can-i-handle-the-warning-of-file-get-contents-function-in-php)

Comment: Got this error: `file_get_contents(https://trafficsecrets.com/ts-free-book): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable`

Comment: @user5955461 Maybe the destination has (temporarily?) blacklisted the server's IP.